# Find rows which have never satistifed a condition

Tags: sql

Say I have a table of customers with three possible statuses: loan default, open loan, paid in full.

How can I find the customers who never defaulted?

Example: John and Alex had multiple loans with different statuses.

```
id | customer | status
----------------------
1     john     default
1     john     open
1     john     paid
2     alex     open
2     alex     paid
```

John defaulted once and Alex never defaulted. A simple `where status <> "default"` attempt doesn't work because it incorrectly includes John's non-defaulted cases. The result should give me:

```
id | customer
-------------
2     alex
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I find the customers who never defaulted?

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select id, customer
from t
group by id, customer
having sum(case when status = 'default' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of defaults for each customer and returns those customers with no defaults.

If you have a separate table of customers, I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.id  = c.id and t.status = 'default'
                 );
```

Comment: The `else` of your `case` is redundant.

Comment: @Bohemian . . . No.  Without the `else` it would return `NULL` and I would have to change the `= 0`.  I prefer `= 0` because I think it is very clear that the expression is saying "the number of rows with `status = 'default'` is 0".

Comment: @Bohemian . . . Right . . . and if all the values are `NULL`, the result is `NULL`, not `0`.

Comment: Exactly. `having sum(case when status = 'default' then 0 end) is null`

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
select distinct `customer` from `customers` 
    where `customer` not in (
        select `customer` from `customers where `status` = 'default'
    );
```

Comment: Note that the `NOT IN (SELECT...` pattern tends to be the least performant of the available options.

Answer (score 0):

The `ALL()` operator with a correlated sub-query works here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (1, 'john', 'default'),
        (1, 'john', 'open'),
        (1, 'john', 'paid'),
        (2, 'alex', 'open'),
        (2, 'alex', 'paid')
    ) AS x(id, customer, status)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte AS a
WHERE 'default' <> ALL (
    SELECT status
    FROM cte AS b
    WHERE a.id = b.id
);
```

If you want just user and/or id, do `select distinct «your desired columns»` instead of `select *`.